# Accesing the component's i18n model from an OpaTest

Tags: sapui5

I am creating OpaTests using the component launcher and i want to match Buttons by text bound to the component's i18n model.

My view looks like:

```xml
<Button press="handleRemove" text="{i18n>xbut.remove}" width="80px" />
```

my test looks like:

```js
iPressRemove: function () {
   return this.waitFor({
       controlType: "sap.m.Button",
       viewName: sViewName,
       matchers: new PropertyStrictEquals({
           name: "text",
           value: "<WHAT GOES HERE>"
       }),
       actions: new Press(),
       errorMessage: "Remove Button not found"
   });
}
```

How do i determine the value of the text from the i18n model?

Answer (score 1):

Load resource model like this:

var sapResourceBundle;
    var oResourceBundle;

```
QUnit.module("Module name", {
  beforeEach: function () {
    this.sapResourceBundle = sap.ui.getCore().getLibraryResourceBundle("sap.m");
    this.oResourceBundle = new ResourceModel({
      bundleUrl: jQuery.sap.getModulePath("your_module", "/i18n/i18n.properties")
    }).getResourceBundle();
  }

});
```

then use oResourceBundle.getText("translation_key")
just like you would in controller

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the answer in the Testing tutorial, you can get the i18n model from the Page

```js
theTitleShouldDisplayTheTotalAmountOfItems: function () {
    return this.waitFor({
        id: "tableHeader",
        viewName: sViewName,
        matchers: function (oPage) {
            var sExpectedText = oPage.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("worklistTableTitleCount", [23]);
            return new PropertyStrictEquals({
                name: "text",
                value: sExpectedText
            }).isMatching(oPage);
        },
        success: function () {
            Opa5.assert.ok(true, "The table header has 23 items");
        },
        errorMessage: "The Table's header does not container the number of items: 23"
    });
}
```

my solution is to store the resource bundle when the page is loaded

```js
var oI18nResourceBundle;

thePageShouldBeVisible: function () {
    return this.waitFor({
        id: "myPage",
        viewName: sViewName,
        success: function (oPage) {
            oI18nResourceBundle = oPage.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle();
            Opa5.assert.ok(true, "Page rendered");
        },
        errorMessage: "Page not rendered."
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from the view:

```js
this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("CHECK_WEBUI");
```